# How should I unit test MySQL queries?

Tags: python, mysql, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I'm building some unit tests for my Python module which interfaces with a MySQL database via SQLAlchemy. From reading around I gather the best way to do this is to create a test database that I can query as if it was the real thing. I've done this however how should I test the existing queries in the module as they currently all point at the live database?

The only idea I'd come up with was to do something like the following:

```
def run_query(engine, db_name='live_db')
    engine.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {db_name}.<table_name>')
```

I could then pass in `test_db` when I run the function from `unittest`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a scalable testing approach, I would suggest having an intermediate DAL Layer than should decide to which DB the query should be routed.

[Testing with a Test Database](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/essential-sqlalchemy-2nd/9781491916544/ch04.html)

Comment: Thanks @Vivek. Neat idea and I also bought the book :-). Would you recommend having two DAL Layers - one for live and one for test? Or just have one for both and build in some tests for that before running the app tests?

Comment: There should be One DAL Layer Only with some flag in it that should help your logic to route your SQL Queries to different Databases.

Comment: That's what I've built. It should be tested too?

Comment: yes you can test the final DB connection string based on ur flag value